# Extracting the array from a List without making it generate a new array

Tags: c#, list, collections

I want to extract the array from a List without using the ToArray() function to make it generate an entire new array.

I don't care about if there is excess in the array, etc, I just want a reference to the array the list uses.

EDIT:

For people who don't understand: The list uses an array internally to store your elements. When you do ToArray(), it actually generates an entire new array, and this can be expensive if the array is large. I simply want a reference to the original array the list uses instead.

Comment: Let us know how you get on

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: @Tyler because I need to give a pointer of the array to a certain function, and for performance I don't want to generate a new array.

Comment: @BlazArt This exact reason is why you should be no more restrictive than needed in function parameters.  Had the writer of the method written it to use an `IList`, or an `IEnumerable` (if he only needed to iterate it) then you wouldn't be in this position.

Comment: @BlazArt You *really* don't want to do this.  The whole point of using a `List` is that the array is an implementation detail that you cannot reason about.  Changes can be made to the implementation of the class that could break code that tries to do this.  If this is truly a need, I would suggest writing your own type that wraps an array and resizes it as needed in which it's a part of its public API that it exposes the underlying array publicly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reflection to get the private field that contains the internal array.

Example:

```
List<string> s = new List<string>();
s.Add("1");
s.Add("2");
s.Add("3");
s.Add("4");

FieldInfo info = s.GetType().GetField("_items", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
string[] items = (string[])info.GetValue(s);

for (int i =  0; i < s.Count; i++) {
  Console.WriteLine(items[i]);
}
```

You are probably aware of this already, but I can't write an answer like this without including it:

- Accessing private members of a framework class is undocumented, and can't be done in a reliable way.
- This only works as long as the name of private field remains the same.
- The array that you get is still used by the list, so changing the array items will affect the list.
- Altering the list will either change array items, or make the list abandon the array and replace it with a new one.
- Items in the array beyond the size of the list (`Count`) can have unpredictable values.

Answer (score 0):

#### veryconfused

I don't understand your question at all but if you want to put your list into another array without using the `.ToArray` then you can always use a `foreach` on the list and go through each element. (Im not sure why you would do this because its very CPU intensive.)

Comment: This is the same as generating a new array. You're just doing it a different way.